# Meta_query by date for Events archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query, custom-post-type-archives

I'm working on a site that has pages for both "Upcoming" and "Archived" events for the "event" custom post type. I set up custom fields (via ACF) for `event_start_date` and `event_end_date` when entering each event, and while I was able to configure the right `meta_query` for the "Upcoming" page, I'm having an issue with the "Archived" page specifically in the case that no end date is entered, i.e. a single-day event in the past. Thus, if possible, I'd like the query to account for (1) when both the start date and end dates are in the past; and (2) when only a start date is entered that's in the past. Here is my query as it exists now:

```
$event_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'event',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => 10,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                    'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '<',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                    'value'   => NULL,
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),
            )        
        ),
    );
```

For reference, my `meta_query` for "Upcoming" events is as follows, and is working fine in cases of single dates and ranges in the future:

```
'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),

        ),
```

Thus, how might I adjust the first `meta_query` for archived events with only a start date entered? Thank you for any assistance here. *UPDATED* adjusted `meta_query` with `NOT EXISTS` per comment below; but still not working as intended.

Comment: Does the `event_end_date` key actually exist for those posts, or should the comparison be `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @Milo that's correct, in this case the `event_end_date` does not exist; I just tried updating the `meta_query` with `NOT EXISTS` as you suggested (see updated question above), and it's still not working in the case that no end date is entered- any ideas? (However, if the same date is entered for start and end and it occurs in the past, it will show up in the archive; I'd like to avoid requiring that step if possible.)

Comment: It might be helpful to look at `$your_wp_query->request` after the query is run to see the SQL being sent to the database, just to verify it's what you expect it to be. Another option, which would result in a more efficient query, would be to hook post save and automatically copy `event_start_date` to `event_end_date` in the case where it doesn't exist, so you can eliminate that check from the query and also not require the user to manually enter a date.

Comment: @Milo- thanks for the response; could you elaborate on how I'd automatically copy `event_start_date` to `event_end_date` in cases that the latter doesn't exist? That seems like a great approach and would indeed simplify things across the board.

Comment: There are some examples on the [`save_post` action codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). I know ACF has its own actions that trigger whenever posts are saved or updated, you might want to look around in their docs and support forums for that.